# multi-monitor setup and arrangement globally (not per user)

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have my desktop arranged with 3x27 monitors, two of which are in portrait mode.  This works fine once I'm logged in to the normal display manager, but makes my lockscreen/login screen terrible (everything is rotated and unusable.)

In addition I have a few secondary user accounts for my friends etc who occasionally use the desktop; the monitor arrangment for them is broken horribly.

For lockscreens I found a few old answers involving hand-editing lightdm files (which don't even exist anymore :/).

What's the proper modern way to fix this?

(I'm going to ask a second question just about this, but I'm particular interested in a solution that'll also fix the question for xmonad, which I prefer to use.)

This applies on Ubuntu 20.04 (and also earlier versions.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `arandr` and `xrandr` to arrange and invoke the **arrangement script** respectively may solve your issue if you:

## First: Arrange the monitors.

In my case I just use a 2 monitor arrangement, but my configuration requires the monitor identified as **HDMI-1** to be vertical, so I use `arandr` to arrange the monitors as I would like them to be used. Please see the next screenshot.

[image]

## Second: Save the screen arrangement script file

Once you're satisfied with your monitors arrangement, just hit the diskette (*I don't know why it is a diskette nowadays but, whatever*), and save your monitors arrangement in a **shell script** (`.sh`)

**Don't forget where did you place the script**

Please notice you can have **as many scripts** as you need for any desktop arrangement, anyway, the same script will work for any user if you use a copy or set the proper execution permissions for every single user.

[image]

In my case, the `screen-home-office-vertical-right.sh` file contains the next code:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 1366x0 --rotate left --output eDP-1 --mode 1366x768 --pos 0x512 --rotate normal
```

Notice that, learning from `xrandr` usage in a terminal will be really useful if you may wish to create your own commands. But if you wish to keep it simple, just go for `arandr`, it will be your best friend.

## Third: Run the script at boot on every user session.

But don't forget to give the script file the proper execution permissions (`chmod +x scriptname.sh`) or use the proper **shell command** to run it (`bash scriptname.sh`).

I am using `i3wm` as my **Tiling Window Manager**, so I can't say for other systems but in `i3wm` is as easy as running the script from `cron`, or from the `i3 config file`, or any other way.

You can also run it manually with a key combination. It is your time to do some research on your Window Manager/Desktop Environment.

## Fourth: Buy me a beer!

Ok no... Just vote for my answer or choose it as accepted if it does the trick for you.

Best regards.